# Create Variable in PHP Equal to Current Time Minus One Hour

Tags: php

In PHP, how could I create a variable called `$livetime` that equals the current time minus 1 hour?

Comment: Are you looking for a particular format?

Comment: No... this value will not be echoed, just used in an IF statement.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Another way - without all the math and, in my opinion, reads better.

```
$hour_ago = strtotime('-1 hour');
```

Answer (score 26):

If you're looking for how to display the time in a human readable format, these examples will help:

```
$livetime = date('H:i:s', time() - 3600); // 16:00:00
$livetime = date('g:iA ', time() - 3600); // 4:00PM
```

Answer (score 12):

```
$livetime = time() - 3600; // 3600 seconds in 1 hour : 60 seconds (1 min) * 60 (minutes in hour)
```

See [time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) PHP function for more information.

Comment: Micro-optimization, `time() - 3600`. Multiplication is expensive.

Comment: :) I wrote 60 * 60 because that would make more sense to OP, I guess. Probably I'd better move it to comment.

Answer (score 5):

convert your date to strtotime and then subtract one hour from it

```
$now =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$time   = strtotime($now);
$time   = $time - (60*60); //one hour
$beforeOneHour = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the date_create function along with the date_sub function like I have shown here below: -

```
$currentTime = date_create(now());
$modifyTime = date_sub($currentTime,date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 hour"));
$liveTime = $modifyTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that a timestamp is fine you can use the [`time`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function like so

```
<?php
$livetime = time() - 60 * 60;
```

Answer (score -1):

Current time is equal to `time()` (current time given in seconds after Unix epoch).

Thus, to calculate what you need, you need to perform calculation: `time() - 60*60` (current time in seconds minus 60 minutes times 60 seconds).

```
$time_you_need = time() - 60*60;
```

Answer (score -1):

First convert hours into seconds (`3600`) then use the following:

```
$your_date = date('F jS, Y',time() - 3600);
```