# How to get 1 hours before

Tags: php

how to get 1 hours before in php

I try with: 

but not working

```
$jam = "10:00:00";
$1hrsbefore = strtotime($jam), strtotime(-1 hours);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Variable in PHP Equal to Current Time Minus One Hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052793/create-variable-in-php-equal-to-current-time-minus-one-hour)

Comment: another similar one, but 'plus 1 hour': https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552106/adding-1-hour-to-time-variable

Comment: @Ajith he is not asking to -1 hour from current time.

Comment: Try this `$oneHourBefore = date("H:i:s", strtotime("10:00:00")-(60*60) );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
$jam = "10:00:00";
$timeadd= strtotime($jam) - 60*60;
$time = date('H:i:s', $timeadd);
echo $time;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$jam="10:00:00";
$time = date('H:i:s', strtotime($jam) - 60*60);
echo $time;
```